# how to get your answers to show up on a new page

Tags: excel, output

The totals show up on a message box and I want them on a new sheet in excel.

```
'Output totals to a message box
   sTtl = "Total stock at " & dStk & " = " & TotStk

    sMsg = "Board No." & vbTab & "Cut Lenght" & vbCrLf

    For k = LBound(DetStk, 2) To UBound(DetStk, 2)
       sMsg = sMsg & DetStk(0, k) & vbTab & vbTab _
            & DetStk(1, k) & vbCrLf
    Next k

    MsgBox sMsg, vbOKOnly, sTtl

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want to put everything that appears in the message box into a single cell on a new sheet or do you want to split the items that are being generated by the For loop in different cells?

Comment: in different cells, it should two columns. One with Board No and the other with Cut Lenght

Answer (score 0):

The code below will create a new sheet and insert the data generated for the message box, including the title and headings, into 2 columns.  You can comment out or delete the message box line `msgbox sMsg, .....` if no longer want it to appear.

```
'Output totals to a message box

Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) ' create a new sheet

sTtl = "Total stock at " & dStk & " = " & TotStk
Range("A1").value = sTtl 'put th title in cell A1

sMsg = "Board No." & vbTab & "Cut Lenght" & vbCrLf
Range("A2").value = "Board No."
Range("B2").value = "Cut Lenght"
Range("A2:B2").Font.Bold = True ' format the headings bold (optional)


intRow = 3 ' set starting row below the heading row.

For k = LBound(DetStk, 2) To UBound(DetStk, 2)
   sMsg = sMsg & DetStk(0, k) & vbTab & vbTab _
        & DetStk(1, k) & vbCrLf
       Range("A"&intRow).value = DetStk(0, k)
       Range("B"&intRow).value = DetStk(1, k)
       intRow = intRow + 1 'add 1 to move to the next row.
Next k

MsgBox sMsg, vbOKOnly, sTtl  'you can delete this line or comment it out with "'" if you don't want to display the message box.

End Sub
```